# Visual C++ console apps on Windows IoT with Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: visual-c++, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

I am just doing some first tests with applications developed with Visual Studio 2015 RC and Windows IoT on Raspberry Pi 2. For a first test I compiled C# Hello World, copied it to the PI via FTP and started it from a powershell. This worked out of the box.
Then I tried the same with a Win32 console application (64-bit), also printing only Hello World. The error message I get in the powershell is:

```
Program 'HelloCpp.exe' failed to run: The operation completed successfully.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [],     ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

I thought, this is to be expected because I did not install the VC++ 2015 (140) runtime. I tried to install this from the powershell in silent mode like this:

```
.\vc_redist.x64.exe /q /norestart
```

but it fails with

```
Program 'vc_redist.x64.exe' failed to run: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform..
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

My question is:
is it possible (or planned) to run C++ background processes like a simple TCP server that I can develop with Visual C++?

Comment: Doesn't the Raspberry Pi 2 have an ARM CPU?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, how could I overlook that! I tried to switch VC2015 (Community Edition) to ARM but that gives me "Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported". I think, even if I could compile it, what about the installation of the suitable runtime lib? Let's see if anyone else has something to say about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all ensure you have followed all of the steps in this [page](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/SetupPCRPI.htm). Should the powers that be change that link again, you are looking for windowsondevices.com -> Get Started -> Set up PC. Once you have done that you should review the sample console app [here](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/ConsoleApp.htm).

I hope that helps.

Mark Radbourne [MSFT]

Comment: That definitely helps, although I hoped I could simply build the app on Windows 8.1 and xcopy to the PI.

Comment: Link dead. That's why we strongly advise against link-only answers.

Comment: Fixed the link and added a comment describing what to look for should the link go bad again.

Comment: Can you please add this to a central documentation area, visible as a new "Setup Visual Studio for debugging different project types" on the getting started "Setup your PC" page. So far I have seen there are three different ways to configure remote debugging for IoT projects (UWP, driver and C++ core). Right now for beginners it seems your luck depends on which sample you happened to choose first.

Comment: I see now the same debug instructions as the memory sample under the first console app sample, so not so bad after all. But please consider adding the debugging instructions separately, up-front somewhere. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Dead link peops :(